# Why does this BBC presenter say "put pay", whereas dictionaries say "put paid"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC Earth Lab YouTube channel, [Life Survives in Extreme Icy Conditions | Earth | BBC Earth Lab](https://youtu.be/cnoyKExpsww?t=15) (see: 0:12-0:22)

> And out here in the biting face of the cold, it's easy to imagine that the endless winter **put pay** to complex life on Earth.

I looked up **"put pay"** in several dictionaries. There are no entries in the form of **"put pay"** but there is a very close one in the form of **"put paid"**.

So, are they both correct, or is the TV presenter using it wrongly?

Comment: He clearly says 'put pay'. It's an error. It should be, as you have said, 'put paid'.

Comment: FYI, as an American (Ohio), I've never heard of either phrasing. Astralbee's answer explains it, but we would not say that phrase and not know what it means. We would say end, terminate, or wipe-out instead in your original example, so it seems to be an idiom of regional use.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Could I just point out that Britain is not a "region" - it is a country, and the one where the English language had its origins.  The expression "put paid to" is widely understood throughout the English-speaking world - the American dictionary, Merriam Webster, listing it - while marking it as "chiefly British". Clearly it belongs to the vast complement of English which is not in extensive use by  the American public - though I think that the more literate and widely-read sections of American society will clearly appreciate its meaning.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean And yes, "end", "wipe-out", and "terminate" are all perfectly well understood and in everyday use in Britain.

Comment: This question had me on tender hooks for a while, but the answer seems to be a damp squid.

Comment: @DaveGremlin I'm assuming the misquotes are deliberate, in which case hilarious!

Comment: @WS2 Not to denigrate Britain, but that is a region of the world just as the USA is a region. https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=region You seem to take my comment as an attack on British English, but it was simply a comment that Americans don't widely use that phrase. The Google ngram site shows it is about five times more common in usage in British English and became a used phrase much earlier than it was in the US. This might be useful information for people running across this thread in the future.

Comment: @Alan That kind of misheard idiom is called an "eggcorn". Rob Words had a fun video on them on YouTube if that's your kind of thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F12LSAbos7A

Comment: American here, and yeah, that phrase is pretty much nonsense to me. I'm sure some Americans know it but only the literate ones who reed they're bookz.

Comment: OP, **it was just a mistake** why is this question not closed ?

Comment: I hear the expression "put paid to" **all the time** in the USA.  I just asked the three other people in this room (ie, everyday yanks, here in the South) if they knew the expression and they all looked at me as if I was strange since of course they knew it.

Comment: @JackAidley and others IMO that's not an eggcorn. At the doctor's if I mispronounce/misunderstand "needle" as "noodle" or "meddle", that is not an eggcorn.  If I mispronounce it as "nettle" - that's an eggcorn.  (A nettle is sort of like a needle.  The other words are meaningless mishearings.)  An eggcorn is the same as a "folk etymology".

Comment: As @WS2 says ... I just went in the other part of the building and asked FOUR 100% regular adult yanks if they knew the phrase "put paid to", and, again, they all looked at me as if I was strange since of course they knew it.

Comment: @Fattie, both "tender hooks" and "damp squid" are, indeed, eggcorns.

Comment: @ I'm from the US Midwest and, like UnhandledExcepSean and Thierry, I feel like I've never heard this phrase and would have difficulty figuring out what it means even from context. I consider myself literate.

Comment: @Fattie - Why does the right answer being that the usage was a mistake suggest that a question asking why the usage was employed should be closed? I think it's a very good question.

Comment: @Fattie Now we know that apparently the American south is one of the regions where it's used. I think I'd get murdered in some parts of the South if I called them yanks though:)

Comment: @WS2 *'The expression "put paid to" is widely understood throughout the English-speaking world'* -- Just want to mention I'm Canadian and also never heard it.

Comment: @tell "America" means the USA in casual speech. If your native language is Spanish, then what you call "America", we call "the Americas" (north and south). For me, I'd be annoyed if you called me "American", cause I'm from Canada, not the US.

Comment: Born in Connecticut, never heard this expression. Time to work on not being illiterate I guess.

Comment: @wjandrea The examples of its use include quotations from the *Manitoba Free Press* of 1930.

Comment: Just to add, I'm from the Western US, and I've never heard the phrase

Comment: **Some comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148335/discussion-on-question-by-yunus-why-does-this-bbc-presenter-say-put-pay-where); please do not continue the discussion about what Britain is or what a region is.** Comments continuing those discussions will be removed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

"*Put paid to...*" is the correct idiom, but quite a few examples of "*put pay to*" [can be found](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put%20pay%20to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) in literature, so BBC presenter Chris Packham is certainly not the first person to say it.

The origin of the phrase supposedly comes from the practice of stamping 'PAID' onto a bill which has been settled, *finalising* it. The idiom doesn't really work with anything but the past tense. A bill with 'PAY' on it sounds like it is still outstanding.

Comment: The earliest usage [one lexicographer](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/put-paid-to.html) could find was from the _Manitoba Morning Free Press_, October 1905, “Wolverhampton Wanderers put paid to Bolton's account, the scores being: 2-0”.  Use of the word “account” may have connected the phrase to the accounting metaphor “settling accounts” or “settling scores”: not only have you wrapped things up, you have done so to your satisfaction.

Comment: google n-grams is probably more useful than a google books search here. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+paid+to%2Cput+pay+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Tristan No, not in this kind of situation and definitely not this particular case. For a start, Google Ngrams IS a search of Google books. Ngrams are good for comparing the use of *valid* words and idioms, not usually wrong ones. And lastly, you have to consider what non-comparable examples the search will return. Click my link and you'll see the first result is not an example of this phrase used incorrectly although the few that follow are. These would skew the results of an ngram.

Comment: @Astralbee I am aware that N-grams is a search of Google books. The N-grams search establishes that "put paid" is overwhelmingly more common, but that "put pay" exists, whilst the google books link only establishes the latter. Given the overall question, establishing the first is also important. I do agree that the underlying search including invalid examples is an issue

Comment: Hmmm... After 34 years in Canada, and then 32 years in the US, that is not an idiom I am familiar with at all.

Comment: Think this might be subjunctive mood?

Comment: If you search Google Books more than half the examples of "put pay to" are of the form *He put "pay to John" on the bill.* NGrams isn't going to be as discerning.

Answer (score 14):

This is an error on the reporter’s side (occurs often while speaking.) According to Collin’s, Cambridge, and Merriam Webster, the correct form is “put paid to.”

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/put-paid-to)

[Word Origin](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/put-paid-to.html)

Comment: The correct and full answer.   It's bizarre we don't simply delete **questions about mistakes**.  The incredible amount of discussion and long-winded answers, created by questions about mistakes, simply **confuses** the OP and future readers.

Comment: Quite so. Listening to the video you can hear the speaker say *put paid to*

Comment: @Fattie the answers (including this one) I see on this question are quite high quality and insightful by general Stack Exchange standards. Even supposing we agree that the reporter made a clear mistake, there is still an interesting underlying question about what the "proper" idiom is (insert here pages of diatribe about linguistic prescriptivism), what the etymology is to justify that usage, and why people might have a different perception.

Comment: Aside from that, it seems there's still an open question as to whether the error - presuming that we accept, prescriptively, that it is an error - was on the part of the speaker or in OP's transcription.

Comment: Karl, I'm afraid I can't agree.  (1) I listened to some of the video in question. I trivially picked out at least 4 places where the speaker mis-speaks one thing or another (as with almost any spoken video, including even the highest budget movies) (2) The issue of the user's exact pronunciation, slurring, whatever, of some particular word in some random video from the millions of video in existence is: utterly irrelevant.  (3) The issue of whether the machine generated close captions are accurate or not is: utterly, utterly irrelevant.  Whilst *YES* the endless ramblings and asides are

Comment: ... in and of themselves "interesting" in the abstract, they have nothing to do with the question at hand, which should just be closed as "typo" or "mistake by speaker".

Answer (score 8):

This is what we'd call an malapropism. The individual in question either misremembered the phrase, or misheard it, and thus said it differently than other listeners might expect. This often happens with homonyms, particularly when a listener doesn't know one of the words in the idiom. In "The IT Crowd", there is a skit where a character confuses "damp squid" for the proper "damp squib," not knowing that a "squib" is a small explosive.

Similarly, since English has various words that sound alike, you'll sometimes find phrases like "bury the lead" instead of "bury the lede," or "tow the line" instead of "toe the line." These have recently been coined eggcorns, and typically present themselves in written, rather than spoken words. This occurs because the idioms use homophones, words that can't be distinguished by hearing alone, requiring context.

Comment: English has a silent T and E in *castle*, it has a silent L in "almond" and "walk" (although I'm aware some Americans do pronounce the L in these words), a silent C in *scent*, a silent G in *sign* and a silent H  in *ghost* and *honest*. A silent R in *car* and also a silent U in *four*. A silent B in *comb*  and *tomb*, so now we have a silent D! What's one silent letter more? :)) :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA How do you pronounce "GHOT"?  The answer is "fish". GH as in rough; o as in women, and T as in nation!

Comment: @WS2  I think that was Ghoti  originally :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You may well be right!

Comment: Eggcorns usually *are* distinguishable by a subtle difference in pronunciation. In my dialect, "eggcorn" itself is noticeably different from the original word "acorn" that it mimics (as a self-referential example). They're also narrower than simple misunderstandings (like "mondegreens" in music lyrics); a proper eggcorn comes with its own, plausible but false etymology. The case of "lede" [is special](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/bury-the-lede-versus-lead) as it's believed the spelling was deliberately invented for the purpose of the idiom.

Comment: Exactly as Karl says, the "lede" example is not ideal here.

Comment: Exactly as Karl says regarding eggcorns, as I mentioned up above *" ... JackAidley and others IMO that's not an eggcorn. At the doctor's if I mispronounce/misunderstand "needle" as "noodle" or "meddle", that is not an eggcorn. If I mispronounce it as "nettle" - that's an eggcorn. (A nettle is sort of like a needle. The other words are meaningless mishearings.) An eggcorn is the same as a "folk etymology".*

Comment: As other's have noted an eggcorn is not just a mispronunciation.  For all intensive purposes, it's a mute point to mention made up words like 'lede'.  It doesn't pass the mustard as an eggcorn.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that the reporter did say "put paid" but that the transcript is wrong.

I'm a New Zealander. I listened to the comment a number of times.
In isolation it does sound like "pay", but my ear-brain system can infer "paid" having been said. No guarantees :-) .

Comment: Much as I want to hear "paid", I just can't. He's saying "pay", with not the slightest hint of the tongue flap that is often all that remains of a word-final /d/.

Comment: @TonyK  What flavour of English do you speak ?  I agree that if it IS there it is very very minimal. But, my NZ brain will not allow it to be abent with complete certainty.

Comment: South-east British English. I reckon it's your brain, not your ear!

Comment: I'd guess that he's saying "paid", but the trailing 'd' is being elided in favour of the 't' of the next word. It's lazy speech that fails to clearly pronounce all syllables, rather than using the wrong word.

Comment: It's a great point about the transcription. There are more and more quewtions on here where someone Eagerly! points out a typo *in the subtitles* of some idiotic youtube video.  Infuriating.

Comment: It’s not just possible – it is unquestionably the case. He very clearly says _paid_, not _pay_. There’s even a pause after the /d/. Yes, the /d/ is quite weakly pronounced, but it’s quite unmistakably there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Where are you located, and what languages do you speak, and from what background? I ask because this seems to depend on a person's underlying "conditioning". New Zealanders  have a distinctibeve accent (unless you are a NZer), but seem able to understand ccented English better than most other perople (in my experuience and perception). As per my answere, I hear the 'd' but not solidly. You seem top hear it with more certainty.  Wheras TonyK cannot hear it.  And simon Geard is somewhat on the fence.

Comment: @TonyK See latest comments by Jnus Bahs and I .

Comment: @Russell My linguistic background is… complicated. The English part of it is an admixture of fairly conservative SSBE (not too dissimilar from the presenter here) and fairly neutral broadcast-ish American, both influenced by growing up in non-English-speaking areas.